# Why do we multiply by 2 PI to create a circle

Tags: math

I am learning opengl and in the code for creating a circle or any circular shape.

Why do we multiply by 2 PI ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < iSegments + 1; i++)
    {
        float angle = 2.0f * M_PI * i / iSegments;

}
```

Comment: Well, you could try using just `PI` or using `3 * PI` and see what happens, right?

Comment: @Ken white i did try with PI it is half circle.

Comment: Then that explains why you need to multiply by 2, doesn't it? Didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @Ken white i wanted to know why does 2 * PI forms a circle which is now clear with the answer given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a total circle radian is 2 * PI？
the angle = ratio * total_radian

Comment: incase if we divide by 2 pi what would that mean ?